# Pointing a subdomain to another IP via Apache

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

Is it possible, using only Apache, to point a subdomain at a specific IP address?

We currently have a primary domain(www.example.com) with 250+ subdomains(site1.example.com, site2.example.com, etc). Due to rules regarding an SSL cert, we now have to place www.example.com on it's own IP address(although it still resides on the same server).

The subdomains are currently configured as alias records, so creating 250+ new A records for each subdomain would be a major hassle.

I would love an Apache-based solution to this problem so that I don't have to spend the rest of my day configuring DNS records.

Comment: I've voted to move this to serverfault.com because I think this would be more appropriate there. If others agree it will (probably) be moved automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the StackExchange network and wasn't aware that serverfault.com existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) pass all requests from one virtual host to another server, which sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin you@your.com
        ServerName your.vhost.your.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyErrorOverride On
        ProxyPass / http://your.realhost.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://your.realhost.com/
        <Location />
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

You could also do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and the [P] option, which can give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do a little testing with it and if it meets my needs I will come back and award you with the answer.

Comment: Not sure how well this will work with SSL - at the very least, you'd need to set `*:443` and `https:` as well; I'm not sure which SSL certificate wiil be used in case of proxying.

Comment: The SSL certificate exposed will be the one of the server using mod_proxy. Assuming it's a wildcard certificate or got all of the domains listed in the certificate it will work ok. You don't actually *have* to use SSL from the proxy to the real server either.

Comment: @awoodland: I did a little looking around and playing with it, and I am a little confused. I just wanted to make sure I'm understanding the concept correctly. `your.vhost.your.com` should be `site1.example.com`. `http://your.realhost.com` should be `www.example.com`. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming I've understood your question correctly the realhost one is the IP or DNS name for the server you really want to serve the request, whereas the your.vhost.your.com is the name of the DNS alias

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I understood. This looks like it should work out for me.